# CakePHP delete() model method failing

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been having an issue with the `$this->delete()` method that deletes a record from the corresponding model. Previously I had the statement contained in an if statement that would detect a `return false;` coming back from the `delete()` and then fail.

The problem is that it fails 100% of the time. I have gone through and double checked the relationships quite a few times to make sure I'm taking care of, and deleting all dependencies prior to deleting this record.

Currently I have removed the statement from the "if" block and just made it execute no matter what and it works without error.

If I was getting a false returned before, shouldn't I be seeing some sort of error?

Ex:

```
if ($this->customeDelete($id)) {
    if ($this->ModelName->ModelName2->ModelName3->customDelete($id)) {
        if ($this->ModelName4->deleteAll(array('foreign_id' => $id))) {

            // Prior to this line, all deletes were successful. This is where it fails. 
            //The previous lines are custom model methods

            if ($this->delete($id)) {  // If statement that is failing
                $this->commit();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your model define a `beforeDelete` callback? Do you see a DELETE statement in the SQL trace?

Comment: What did your `if` block looked like?

Comment: try with $this->Modelname->delete($id);

Comment: If you copied and pasted this, you might have a spelling error in your first `if` statement. The function `customDelete` is misspelt as `customeDelete`. But as it's already been pointed out, it seems like you're deleting the record with the first `customDelete` call and then again with the `delete` call.

Comment: The "customeDelete" is meant to be "customDelete" but also that actual method doesn't exist. It is meant to be "customDelete". I can't give any actual method names from our software. Just know the function is a few conditional deletes put together based on different flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you call `$this->cutomDelete` on the record you want to delete, and then `$this->delete` on the same record. If customDelete has already deleted the data, then delete won't have anything to delete and therefore will return false.

Comment: Pardon the misunderstanding. It is a custom delete functions that is meant to remove related data, not the final specific record. I tried the best I could to break this down, but because of my job I am unable to display real function names and data.

Comment: Without seeing customDelete this is a little tough... My gut feeling is that the record is being deleted there. Try looking at the order the queries are being run in debug, or alternately try

    `$this->id = $id;
    debug($this->read());`

If it returns an empty array, you'll know for sure it's being deleted earlier in your script. It could be that you're calling a delete without setting cascade to false. 

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1036/delete

Comment: You are very insightful. THank you. Yes, apparently the person who coded the previous delete methods was not passing a false on cascade.